# How are solr and postgreSQL connected in ckan?

Tags: postgresql, solr, ckan

I can't find how solr link to postgreSQL in ckan.

I wrote `solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr`, and `sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:123456@localhost/ckan_default` in my development.ini file, but I'm confused how does solr know that its dataset is ckan_default.

I didn't find config file for solr,`src/ckan/ckan/config/solr/schema.xml`only have filed information. `/var/lib/solr/data` and `/etc/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml` have no dataset information either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CKAN, Solr is not directly linked to PostgreSQL. The Solr index is maintained by the CKAN code itself, see [`ckan.lib.search.index`](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/31b816707ab773ccb6530f90de584883375c0a2f/ckan/lib/search/index.py). Extensions can hook into the indexing via the [`before_index` method](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IPackageController.before_index) of the [`IPackageController` interface](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IPackageController).

Comment: Thank you! I understand!

Comment: @薇薇安: Great, glad I could help you! Please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that after `localhost/`, the database name is stated. In this case, it's `ckan_default`.

Comment: But I can't find postgresql message in solr config file, so how solr connect to postgresql, the development.ini is config file of ckan, not solr.